# PHP: cannot retrieve data from radio button POST

Tags: php, post, radio-button

I'm having issues with retrieving data from the radio button. I can retrieve other data from the other html tags but in radio button I cannot. Why is that? Can you help me?

My HTML code is here:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="markpayment" method="post" action="test.app">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mark_payment">
  <input type="hidden" name="client-id" value="{$details[row]->id}">
  <input type="hidden" name="invoice-id" value="{$details[row]->invoice_id}">
  <input type="hidden" name="period" value="{$details[row]->period}">
  <table width="100%" border="0" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="radiobut">
        <input type="radio" id="choice1" name="payment_status" value="paid"> Paid</td>
      <td class="radiobut">
        <input type="radio" id="choice2" name="payment_status" value="declined"> Declined</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="paddingRow3">
          <select class="selectbut" id="payments" name="payment-method">
            <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
            <option value="Deposit">Deposit</option>
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="right">
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="paddingRow3">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="update" onclick="document.markpayment.submit()">Update</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

While my PHP script is here:

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'mark_payment'){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    exit;
}
```

My output will be just like this:

```
Array
(
    [NONCE] => f305790c4d8b060121b99fe84a8fdf1a62321b3b06b9097caa8439e2f9c5bae7
    [action] => mark_payment
    [client-id] => 2699422
    [invoice-id] => 13008351
    [period] => 11
    [payment-method] => Cheque
)
```

Comment: did you click/select any of the radio options?

Comment: @Akintunde i did but it didn't work

Comment: @Akintunde's comment is correct. For testing can you set checked="true" for one of the radios and see if the value reaches the server?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate `name` attributes of `payment_status` for your two choices. They need to be different, or only the last input element (`#choice2`) will be available.

I've gone with `payment_status_paid` and `payment_status_declined` in the following example, but you can also use the square bracket notation `name="payment_status[]"` to make an **array** of `POST` data.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="markpayment" method="post" action="test.app">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mark_payment">
  <input type="hidden" name="client-id" value="{$details[row]->id}">
  <input type="hidden" name="invoice-id" value="{$details[row]->invoice_id}">
  <input type="hidden" name="period" value="{$details[row]->period}">
  <table width="100%" border="0" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="radiobut">
        <input type="radio" id="choice1" name="payment_status_paid" value="paid"> Paid</td>
      <td class="radiobut">
        <input type="radio" id="choice2" name="payment_status_declined" value="declined"> Declined</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="paddingRow3">
          <select class="selectbut" id="payments" name="payment-method">
            <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
            <option value="Deposit">Deposit</option>
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="right">
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="paddingRow3">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="update" onclick="document.markpayment.submit()">Update</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

To find which one is chosen, use a conditional:

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'mark_payment'){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    if ($_POST['payment_status_paid']) {
      // Payment was successful
    }
    else {
      // Payment was declined
    }
    exit;
}
```

Hope this helps!